# How to publish mirrored tf?

Tags: ros, react-navigation-stack

I attempted to use [rf2o laser_to_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rf2o_laser_odometry) for the navigation stack. However, tf goes to the wrong orientation when I move the robot. i.e. when I move the robot to right, the tf goes to left.

For the configuration of the lidar: I rotated my lidar 90 degrees around z-direction and flipped upside down, and it scans only half range, from -180 to 0 degree.

tf setup is correct, I checked again with hector slam while creating the map, `args="0.2 0 0 1.57 3.14  0 /base_link /laser_frame 40`, also this problem doesn't occur while I didn't flip the lidar upside down (and also changed the tf static publisher to the back to `args="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser_frame 40`)

The following is the code [(also can be found here)](https://github.com/MAPIRlab/rf2o_laser_odometry/blob/master/src/CLaserOdometry2DNode.cpp) I find in CLaserOdometry2DNode.cpp of the rf2o package..Will that be something wrong here causing the tf is not read correctly in the package, or is that any way to edit this, to mirror the tf (left and right, i.e. mirror along y-axis)?

appreciate if anyone can help!!

```
    // Set laser pose on the robot (through tF)
    // This allow estimation of the odometry with respect to the robot base reference system.
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    transform.setIdentity();
    try
    {
      tf_listener.lookupTransform(base_frame_id, last_scan.header.frame_id, ros::Time(0), transform);
      retrieved = true;
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException &ex)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
      ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
      retrieved = false;
    }

    //TF:transform -> Eigen::Isometry3d

    const tf::Matrix3x3 &basis = transform.getBasis();
    Eigen::Matrix3d R;

    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
      for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        R(r,c) = basis[r][c];

    Pose3d laser_tf(R);

    const tf::Vector3 &t = transform.getOrigin();
    laser_tf.translation()(0) = t[0];
    laser_tf.translation()(1) = t[1];
    laser_tf.translation()(2) = t[2];

    setLaserPose(laser_tf);

    return retrieved;
  }
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the tf tree
[tf tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB9di.png)

I tried to understand the package, knowing that after it listen for the tf, which is the code attached up there, it passes the value to setLaserPose:

```
void CLaserOdometry2D::setLaserPose(const Pose3d& laser_pose)
{
  //Set laser pose on the robot

  laser_pose_on_robot_     = laser_pose;
  laser_pose_on_robot_inv_ = laser_pose_on_robot_.inverse();
}
```

and convert the final result which is robot_pose_ with respect to the tf,see below: However, I find that both  ROS_INFO_COND message are the same, showing no difference.. Seems *laser_pose_on_robot_inv_* is not converting the result...May I have some advice on how to deal with this?

```
  ROS_INFO_COND(verbose, "[rf2o] LASERodom = [%f %f %f]",
            laser_pose_.translation()(0),
            laser_pose_.translation()(1),
            rf2o::getYaw(laser_pose_.rotation()));

  //Compose Transformations
  robot_pose_ = laser_pose_ * laser_pose_on_robot_inv_;

  ROS_INFO_COND(verbose, "BASEodom = [%f %f %f]",
            robot_pose_.translation()(0),
            robot_pose_.translation()(1),
            rf2o::getYaw(robot_pose_.rotation()));
```

also tf in rviz
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msnwF.png)

launch file for rf2o (which is robot_configuration in navigation stack)

```
<launch>
  <node name="ydlidar_node"  pkg="ydlidar"  type="ydlidar_node" output="screen">
    <param name="port"         type="string" value="/dev/ydlidar"/>  
    <param name="baudrate"     type="int"    value="115200"/>
    <param name="frame_id"     type="string" value="laser_frame"/>
    <param name="angle_fixed"  type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="low_exposure"  type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="heartbeat"    type="bool"   value="false"/>
    <param name="resolution_fixed"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
    <param name="angle_min"    type="double" value="-180" />
    <param name="angle_max"    type="double" value="0" />
    <param name="range_min"    type="double" value="0.08" />
    <param name="range_max"    type="double" value="16.0" />
    <param name="ignore_array" type="string" value="" />
    <param name="samp_rate"    type="int"    value="9"/>
    <param name="frequency"    type="double" value="7"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_to_base_link"
    args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_footprint /base_link 40" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser_frame"
    args="0.3 0 0 1.57 3.14 0 /base_link /laser_frame 40" />

  <node pkg="rf2o_laser_odometry" type="rf2o_laser_odometry_node" name="rf2o_laser_odometry" output="screen">
    <param name="laser_scan_topic" value="/scan"/>        # topic where the lidar scans are being published
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true" />                   # wheter or not to publish the tf::transform (base->odom)
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_footprint"/>      # frame_id (tf) of the mobile robot base. A tf transform from the laser_frame to the base_frame is mandatory
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom" />                # frame_id (tf) to publish the odometry estimations    
    <param name="init_pose_from_topic" value="" /> # (Odom topic) Leave empty to start at point (0,0)
    <param name="freq" value="40.0"/>                            # Execution frequency.
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find mobilet_2dnav)/rviz_cfg/configuration.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

Comment: Please post a picture of your TF tree through RVIZ, so we have an idea what might be going on.

Comment: I edited the question with the tf tree and more details of the code. Can you please have a look

Comment: I meant an image in rviz as shown on https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8866/17745

Comment: Attached in the question, please find the photo

Comment: I'd suggest solving the issue by making sure the laser sensor frame id correctly reflects its location on the robot. Eg. If the laser is looking forward, in rviz you should see everything correctly show in the laser with respect to the robot. As long as that and the TF tree is correct, everything should follow.  I would suggest against manually fudging it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to be sure that the tf reflects the correct laser sensor frame with respect to the robot... I have tested the same tf configuration with hector_slam, and it works ok..so I would like to see if any changes in the package would make it right

Comment: Can you share the launch file you are using for rf2o

Comment: I placed it in the edit part as well. Please have a look

Comment: Why is the z axis of your laser upside down in the rviz image?  Is the sensor mounted upside down?

Comment: Yes, the laser is mounted upside down and also rotated around z axis for 90 degree

Comment: The only other thing I can think for why .inverse() doesn't seem to inverse the pose might be because it maybe unable to receive the transform via tf_listener.lookupTransform and then go into the catch exception in which case it keeps the transform.setIdentity() assigned before the try block.  Can you confirm this is not the case?

Comment: oh yes...I finally figure out there is an error 
`[ERROR] [1554284687.837967130]: "base_footprint" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.` 
I also tried to run `rosrun tf tf_echo base_footprint laser_frame`, but it is not empty, it shows

`At time 1554285619.658

- Translation: [0.300, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.707, 0.707, 0.001, 0.001]
            in RPY (radian) [3.142, 0.002, -1.572]
            in RPY (degree) [180.000, 0.091, -90.046]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for Vik for leading.
So it seems that the tf is yet to be in the buffer when listening.
It works now after waiting for the transform:

For the CLaserOdometry2DNode.cpp,
I add a line

```
tf_listener.waitForTransform("/base_footprint","/laser_frame", ros::Time(), ros::Duration(5.0));
```

before the `tf_listener.lookupTransform`

hope this helps for the ones using rf2o laser_to_odometry.